# How to get the max row count grouped by the ID in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, filter, group-by

Say I have this table: 
(column: `Row` is a count based on the column `ID`)

```
ID  | Row  | State | 
1   | 1    | CA    |
1   | 2    | AK    |
2   | 1    | KY    |
2   | 2    | GA    |
2   | 3    | FL    |
3   | 1    | WY    |
3   | 2    | HI    |
3   | 3    | NY    |
3   | 4    | DC    |
4   | 1    | RI    |
```

I'd like to generate a new column that would have the highest number in the `Row` column grouped by the `ID` column for each row. How would I accomplish this? I've been messing around with MAX(), GROUP BY, and some partitioning but I'm getting different errors each time. It's difficult to finesse  this correctly. Here's my target output:

```
ID  | Row  | State | MaxRow
1   | 1    | CA    | 2
1   | 2    | AK    | 2
2   | 1    | KY    | 3
2   | 2    | GA    | 3
2   | 3    | FL    | 3
3   | 1    | WY    | 4
3   | 2    | HI    | 4
3   | 3    | NY    | 4
3   | 4    | DC    | 4
4   | 1    | RI    | 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use window version of `MAX`:

```
SELECT ID, Row, State, MAX(Row) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS MaxRow
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b5c8/1)

Comment: Thanks! I was using `GROUP BY` where you had your `PARTITION BY`, it'll stick with me eventually...

Comment: A question here, this method can be used in older version of sql server?

Comment: @Juan I think it can be used from Sql Server 2005 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

You could join between a query on the table and an aggregate table:

```
SELECT t.*, max_row
FROM   t
JOIN   (SELECT   id, MAX([row]) AS max_row
        FROM     t
        GROUP BY id) agg ON t.id = agg.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create first a query using group by id and max to get the highest number. Then use this query as a sub query and use the id to inner join.

Then use the max column from the sub query to obtain your final result.